# Inserting cipher text into mysql using python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, cryptography

So i have a program which will encrypt a string using AES and generate cipher which in bytes[].
I wish to store this cipher as it is in mysql database.
I found we could use VARBINARY data type in mysql to do so.

In what ways we could achieve so.

Here is my try to do so :

```
import ast
import mysql.connector
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes



def encrypt(key, msg):
    iv = get_random_bytes(16)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(msg)    # Use the right method here
    db = iv + ciphertext
    print(db)
    cursor.executemany(sql_para_query,db)
    print(cursor.fetchone())
    connection.commit()
    return iv + ciphertext


def decrypt(key, ciphertext):
    iv = ciphertext[:16]
    ciphertext = ciphertext[16:]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    msg = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
    return msg.decode("utf-8")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", database = "test_db", user = "sann", password = "userpass",use_pure=True)
    cursor = connection.cursor(prepared = True)
    sql_para_query = """insert into test1 values(UNHEX(%s)) """
    ed = input("(e)ncrypt or (d)ecrypt: ")
    key = str(1234567899876543)
    if ed == "e":
        msg = input("message: ")
        s= encrypt(key, msg)
        print("Encrypted message: ", s)
        file = open("e_tmp","wb+")
        file.write(s)
        print(type(s))

    elif ed == "d":
        #smsg = input("encrypted message: ")
        #file = open("e_tmp","rb")
        #smsg = file.read()
        #print(type(smsg))
        sql_para_query = """select * from test1"""
        cursor.execute(sql_para_query)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        print(row)
        #smsg = str(smsg)
        #msg = ast.literal_eval(smsg)
        #print(msg)
        #print(type(msg))
        #s=decrypt(key, msg)
        #print("Decrypted message: ", s)
        #print(type(s))
```

Error I'm getting :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/mr_pool/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py",
>   line 1233, in executemany
>       self.execute(operation, params)   File "/home/mr_pool/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py",
>   line 1207, in execute
>       elif len(self._prepared['parameters']) != len(params): TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tmp1.py", line 36, in
>   
>       s= encrypt(key, msg)   File "tmp1.py", line 14, in encrypt
>       cursor.executemany(sql_para_query,db)   File "/home/mr_pool/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py",
>   line 1239, in executemany
>       "Failed executing the operation; {error}".format(error=err)) mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation;
>   object of type 'int' has no len()

Any other alternatives are also welcome.

My ultimate goal is to store the encrypted text in database.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your error, but it seems there are more errors in your code.
The key as well as the message are strings, therefore I got this error:

```
TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code
```

Which I fixed by encoding them in utf-8:

```
# line 38:
key = str(1234567899876543).encode("utf8")
# .... line 41:
s= encrypt(key, msg.encode("utf8"))
```

The UNHEX function in your SQL Query is not needed because we are entering the data as VARBINARY. You can change your statement to:

```
"""insert into test1 values(%s) """
```

The function executemany() can be replaced by execute() because you are only entering one statement. However I will write the solution for using both, execute or executemany.

**insert with execute():**

From the documentation:

> cursor.execute(operation, params=None, multi=False)
>
> iterator = cursor.execute(operation, params=None, multi=True)
>
> This method executes the given database operation (query or command). The **parameters found in the tuple or dictionary** params are bound to the variables in the operation. Specify variables using %s or %(name)s parameter style (that is, using format or pyformat style). execute() returns an iterator if multi is True. 
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

So we need just to build a tuple with your parameters by changing the cursor.execute line to:

```
cursor.execute(sql_para_query, (db, ))
```

**insert with executemany():**

From the documentation:

> cursor.executemany(operation, seq_of_params)
>   This method prepares a database operation (query or command) and executes it against all parameter sequences or mappings **found in the sequence seq_of_params**. 
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html

Therefore we need to build a sequence with values you'd like to insert. In your case just one value:

```
 cursor.executemany(sql_para_query, [(db, )])
```

To insert multiple values, you can add as many tuples into your sequence as you want.

**full code:**

```
import ast
import mysql.connector
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

def encrypt(key, msg):
    iv = get_random_bytes(16)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(msg)    # Use the right method here
    db = iv + ciphertext
    cursor.execute(sql_para_query, (db, ))
    connection.commit()
    return iv + ciphertext


def decrypt(key, ciphertext):
    iv = ciphertext[:16]
    ciphertext = ciphertext[16:]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    msg = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
    return msg.decode("utf-8")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", database = "test_db", user = "sann", password = "userpass",use_pure=True)
    cursor = connection.cursor(prepared = True)
    sql_para_query = """insert into test1 values(%s) """
    ed = input("(e)ncrypt or (d)ecrypt: ")
    key = str(1234567899876543).encode("utf8")
    if ed == "e":
        msg = input("message: ")
        s= encrypt(key, msg.encode("utf8"))
        print("Encrypted message: ", s)
        file = open("e_tmp","wb+")
        file.write(s)
        print(type(s))

    elif ed == "d":
        sql_para_query = """select * from test1"""
        cursor.execute(sql_para_query)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        msg = row[0] # row is a tuple, therefore get first element of it
        print("Unencrypted message: ", msg)
        s=decrypt(key, msg)
        print("Decrypted message: ", s)
```

**output:**

```
#encrypt:
(e)ncrypt or (d)ecrypt: e
message: this is my test message !!
Encrypted message:  b"\x8f\xdd\xe6f\xb1\x8e\xb51\xc1'\x9d\xbf\xb5\xe1\xc7\x87\x99\x0e\xd4\xb2\x06;g\x85\xc4\xc1\xd2\x07\xb5\xc53x\xb9\xbc\x03+\xa2\x95\r4\xd1*"
<class 'bytes'>
#decrypt:
(e)ncrypt or (d)ecrypt: d
Unencrypted message:  bytearray(b"\x8f\xdd\xe6f\xb1\x8e\xb51\xc1\'\x9d\xbf\xb5\xe1\xc7\x87\x99\x0e\xd4\xb2\x06;g\x85\xc4\xc1\xd2\x07\xb5\xc53x\xb9\xbc\x03+\xa2\x95\r4\xd1*")
Decrypted message:  this is my test message !!
```